# bash: "logical and" checks if file exists?

Tags: bash

In bash, the usual way to check if file exists is `[ -f xxxx ]` or `[ -e xxxx ]`.
I see a script doing this `if [ -a xxxx ]`, and I verified that this works to check the existence of a file. How is "logical and" operation being used to do this?

Comment: As seen in the duplicated, it is deprecated, hence you don't see it in `man test`. However, if you do `help test` you will see "-a FILE        True if file exists.".